# Javascript -- Convert String to Constant

Tags: javascript, string

How to convert a string to constant in Javascript

e.g

str = "User"
//Javascript magic
User

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't -- JavaScript does not have constants, nor readonly variables.  (Some extensions to JavaScript provide for read-only *accessors*, but that's something else entirely.)

Comment: Actually I wanted to do this => `str="key:value" arr=str.split(':') obj={arr[0]:arr[1]}` how can I do this?

Comment: Hmm, that looks nothing at all like the question you asked.  But here you go: `var str = "key:value"; var arr = str.split(':'); var obj = {}; obj[arr[0]] = arr[1];`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such thing as constants in Javascript. But you could create an object that will expose this information as read-only properties:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function defineConstant(obj, name, value) {
        // Non-standard!
        if(obj.__defineGetter__) {
            obj.__defineGetter__(name, function () { return value; });
            obj.__defineSetter__(name, function() { throw "Read-only property"; });
        } else {
            if(typeof(Object.defineProperty) != 'undefined') {
                try {
                // First, trying the "normal" way
                defineReadOnlyProperty(obj, name, value);
                } catch(ex) {
                    var temp = obj;

                    // Ugly hack to make "defineProperty" work in IE
                    // (only works on DOM elements prior IE9)
                    obj = document.createElement('DIV');

                    // Copying object members
                    for(var key in temp)
                        obj[key] = temp[key];

                    // Now it should define property
                    defineReadOnlyProperty(obj, name, value);
                }
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }

    function defineReadOnlyProperty(obj, name, value) {
        Object.defineProperty(obj, name, {
            get: function() { return value; },
            set: function() { throw "Read-only property"; }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And the usage of above function will look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    var Global = {};

    Global = defineConstant(Global, 'MagicUser', 'User');           

    // Getting "User"
    alert(Global.MagicUser);

    // Throws an error
    Global.MagicUser = 'User2';
</script>
```

Hope this will help you.